# Highcharts: Tick point and x axis point is far from each other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts

One issue is that the first point of line is at 15th jul but 15th july is not showing on x axis, it shows when you hover on it, and the first point of column is on 8th july. 
Second issue is both points (of bar and line) have distance, it should be align opposite to each other.
[image]

```
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: [{
        type: 'datetime'
    }, {
        type: 'datetime'

    }],
    series: [{field_name: "ordered_revenue",   type: "spline",   name: "Grouped ordered_revenue",   connectNulls: true,   data:     [[1531681200000, 566.76],
[1531767600000, 604.26],
[1531854000000, 742.78],
[1531940400000, 545.55],
[1532026800000, 252.16],
[1532113200000, 468.67],
[1532199600000, 426.68]]},  {field_name: "ordered_revenue",   type: "column",   name: "Grouped ordered_revenue Prior Priod",   connectNulls: true,   xAxis: 1,   data:     [[1531681200000, 510.61],
[1531767600000, 346.74],
[1531854000000, 327.57],
[1531940400000, 269.34],
[1532026800000, 372.34],
[1532113200000, 231.38],
[1532199600000, 442.09]]}]

});
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: yes dear  how can I show the first point and in equal alignment.

Comment: Probably by giving proper coordinates, but can't help with that since you have no code to show how they are being plotted, hun.

Comment: ok I can edit my question with little code

Comment: Please check I have updated my question with code @ForeverZer0

Comment: Hi Qumber Ali, why do you use two xAxis? Everything looks much better with one xAxis: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xov9pd67/

Comment: Because I'm using prior periods so i need data of this month and also the data of same month of last year. that's why i need t x axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column series causes another way of rendering xAxis. You need to set **pointPlacement** on the column series to **on**.

```
series: [{
    field_name: "ordered_revenue",
    type: "spline",
    name: "Grouped ordered_revenue",
    connectNulls: true,
    data: [
        [1531681200000, 566.76],
        [1531767600000, 604.26],
        [1531854000000, 742.78],
        [1531940400000, 545.55],
        [1532026800000, 252.16],
        [1532113200000, 468.67],
        [1532199600000, 426.68]
    ]
}, {
    field_name: "ordered_revenue",
    type: "column",
    pointPlacement: 'on',
    name: "Grouped ordered_revenue Prior Priod",
    connectNulls: true,
    xAxis: 1,
    data: [
        [1531681200000, 510.61],
        [1531767600000, 346.74],
        [1531854000000, 327.57],
        [1531940400000, 269.34],
        [1532026800000, 372.34],
        [1532113200000, 231.38],
        [1532199600000, 442.09]
    ]
}]
```

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointPlacement

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qp3wcgxo/